# Install 64 bit window service - NSIS

Tags: nsis

Want to install a 64bit windows service using NSIS packaging tool.
I have used NSIS before to install 32 bit windows service using NSIS tool. I used SimpleSC package lib. I used this command line to install 32 bit service.

```
SimpleSC::InstallService [name_of_service] [display_name] [service_type] [start_type] 
  [binary_path] [dependencies] [account] [password]
```

However, dont know how to install 64bit windows service.
Does NSIS support 64bit?

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any difference between 32 and 64 bit services, they are all registered in the same place the and normal API should work everywhere.

If you have 64-bit exe files you might want to use those on 64-bit systems:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include x64.nsh

Section "Install service"
SetOutPath $Instdir
${If} ${IsNativeAMD64}
    File "myfiles\amd64\mysvc.exe"
${Else}
    File "myfiles\x86\mysvc.exe"
${EndIf}  
SimpleSC::InstallService ... "$Instdir\mysvc.exe" ...
Pop $0
SectionEnd
```